# Angularjs: Add LIs to an already existing UL which also has an LI in it

Tags: angularjs

If I wanted to have an existing `UL` which has an existing `LI` in it.
And then, there would be a directive or component that dropped in dynamic `LI`s in its place... for example:

```html
<div ng-controller='myctrl'>
    <ul>
      <li>already here</li>
      <hello-world></hello-world>
    </ul>    
<div>
```

would become:

```html
<div ng-controller='myctrl'>
    <ul>
      <li>already here</li>
      <li>I be dynamic. much cool</li>
      <li>I too be dynamic. many wow</li>
    </ul>    
<div>
```

What's the best approach to this?

Here's my code so far with what i'd like to have happen:

```js
angular.module('components', []).directive('helloWorld', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<li>I be dynamic. much cool</li><li>I too be dynamic. many wow</li>',
        controllerAs: "vm",
        replace:true,
        controller: [function(){
            var ctrl = this;
            ctrl.$onInit = function() {
              // 
            };
        }]
    };
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/efqv5puc/2/

Comment: Any AngularJS component that removes its DOM entry-point is self-destructive. It is better to place a directive on the <ul> and use classes (or even better, data attributes) on the dynamic <li> for the directive to reference. 

It's also important to consider the lifetime of your dynamic elements. Placing elements under invalid parent elements isn't great (<ul> can only have <li> children), you can do it, but parsers will identify them as errors. If you can avoid using placeholder elements and drive it all from a directive on the <ul>, that would be better. Need the 'why' to advise further.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I agree. We have an unfortunate sticking point that it feels we are "having" to get around. Having said that, I have tried multi transclusion which is very similar to just using a directive with an in-line template... So I think your comment is well placed. Thank you. transclusion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44791456/angularjs-multi-slot-transclusion